# When testing with rspec, where to put common "test utility methods"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

Suppose you have a shopping site that sells widgets.  However, the inventory of each widget is limited, so it's important to keep the "widget.number_still_available" number up to date.

I'd like to write an rspec test along the lines of

```
it "always displays the correct number still available" do

   # Assume there is a before method that sets up a widget with 5 available

   widget.number_still_available.should == 5

   # User "a@b.com" purchases 2 widgets
   widget.number_still_available.should == 3

   # User "c@d.com" purchases 1 widget
   widget.number_still_available.shhould == 2

   # User "a@b.com" cancels purchase of 1 widget
   widget.number_still_available.should == 4
end
```

I'd like to be able to write testing-only methods that performs the "purchasing" and "canceling" methods.  These actions don't correspond to any "real" methods in my models for a variety of reasons (most significantly there is a decoupled back-end system in PHP that performs part of the purchasing and canceling actions).

Where is the correct place to put this code when using RSpec?  In cucumber, I could write a couple of steps - but I'm not sure what the correct equivalent is for RSpec.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would suggest making a new file in `spec/support` called `purchase_helpers.rb` and put this content in it:

```
module PurchaseHelpers
  def purchase_widgets(user, count=1)
    # Code goes here
  end

  def cancel_purchase(user, count=1)
    # Code goes here
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include PurchaseHelpers
end
```

The benefit of doing this rather than chucking it into `spec/spec_helper.rb` is that it is not crowding up that file with a lot of unrelated-to-the-setup-of-RSpec code. Separating things out is the better way to do things.

Comment: Note that it does also work to monkey patch model classes in this same file. So, if you preferred `purchase_widgets` to be a test-only method on User, you can open the User class in this file and add it.  Also, for extra convenience, if you are testing with Spork, you might want to add `load "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/purchase_helpers.rb"` inside the `Spork.each_run` block in spec_helper.rb.

Comment: That last bit is only necessary if you want to include `PurchaseHelper` methods in the namespace of all specs.  If you want to do it only when needed, you can call `include PurchaseHelpers` in your `describe` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can drop a monkeypatch into **spec_helper.rb**, or directly at the top of the spec file if it's only used for that one file.

It would be more clear and safe to make helper methods which use existing class methods, instead of monkeypatching the classes.